# Неизменяемые и изменяемые объекты в python. Срезы

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

Разбираюсь в деталях питона. Попробовал вот такой пример и удивился.

```
x = [1,5,2,3,4]
print(id(x))
print(id(x[::-1]))
print(id(sorted(x)), id(x))

140403956176968
140403956176264
140403956176264 140403956176968
```

- Почему для инвертированного среза и отсортированного списка оказываются одинаковыми id?
- Есть ли в питоне тип slice? Например, такой код `print(type(x[:]))` говорит тип `<class 'list'>`.
- Является ли срез изменяемым типом или нет?

Comment: Подозреваю, что питон оптимизирует выполнение и переиспользует выделенную память под список, который не захвачен переменной.Если ввести переменные, то id станут разными

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему для инвертированного среза и отсортированного списка оказываются одинаковыми id?

Это случайность, на которую не следует рассчитывать. `x[::-1]` у вас создаёт *временный* список, к моменту когда вы вызываете `sorted(x)`, который ещё один список создаёт, список, созданный `x[::-1]`, уже может быть удалён и его память может быть под новый список использована, как ваш пример демонстрирует.

Что `[:]` делает, зависит от конкретного типа (что `__getitem__` метод делает). Для списков `L[:]` создаёт новый список (shallow copy). Для других типов, другие значения, к примеру:

```
>>> range(10)[::-1]
range(9, -1, -1)
```

Соответственно результат `[:]` может быть и изменяемым и неизменяемым в зависимости от типа (и даже конкретных аргументов).

Answer (score 0):

всё потому что Вы всё время работаете с одим и темже вписком. попробуйте:

```
x = [1,5,2,3,4]
print(id(x))
y = x[::-1]
print(id(y))
print(id(sorted(x)), id(x))
```

результат Вас немного удивит.